# Get PDF file url from Slack and convert to base64 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, slack, slack-api

I have a scenario where the user uploads a PDF to the Slack bot. I fetch the URL from the Slack response and pass it to the base64 encoder. The encoder looks like:

```
def convertPdfToBase64(url):
    page = urllib.request.Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(urllib.request.urlopen(page).read()).decode("utf-8")
    return encoded_string
```

When I pass the URL to the convertPdfToBase64(), it returns the encoded string as HTML document and not as PDF. I even tried to get the redirected URL but did not work.

**Slack response URL example:** https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T01ASGU49-F01BPN6GSFM/file__1_.pdf

**Redirected URL from requests.head():** https://microsoft-rm67093.slack.com/?redir=%2Ffiles-pri%2FT01AU49-F01BPSFM%2Ffile__1_.pdf

```
r = requests.head('https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T01ASGU49-F01BPN6GSFM/file__1_.pdf', allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
```

However, when I take the URL that I got initially from the response and paste it in the browser, it redirects to a different link than the one I got from requests.head(), and after passing that URL to the convertPdfToBase64(), I get the right base64 encoded string.

**Browser redirects to:** https://slack-files.com/files-pri-safe/T01ASG1PU49-F01BGSFM/file__1_.pdf?c=16014784-3a7c2a18cefbef

What am I missing here? How can I get the URL that was redirected by the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding page.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) works.